# @ResourceDependency not working when attached to a Renderer

Tags: spring, jsf, jakarta-ee

I have a single custom component defined and 2 renderers i can switch between. One of the renderers uses client javascript and needs to send that lib to the :head element.

When `@ResourceDepedency` is attached to the custom component - `public class SomeCustComp extends UIInput`, it works as expected. But when:

```
@ResourceDependency(name="SomeLib.js", target="head")
@FacesRenderer(componentFamily="custom-renderers", rendererType="variant2")
public class AnotherRendererVariant extends Renderer {...
```

The resulting page wouldn't include the script in the `<head>` element.

I tried to add the element programmatically in the render's `encodeEnd()` via:

```
UIComponent script = (UIComponent)ctx.getApplication().createComponent("javax.faces.Output");
script.setRendererType("javax.faces.resource.Script");
script.getAttributes().put("name", "SomeLib.js");
script.getAttributes().put("target", "head");
context.getViewRoot().addComponentResource(context,  script, "head");
```

But that doesn't work as well.

The docs explicitly state that implementations must support `@ResourceDepedency` for custom components and custom renderers. I guess mine doesn't - tomcat8, spring5.

Has anyone faced such issue?

Comment: Why do you have one custom component with two renderers and not two custom components?

Comment: @Kukeltje , i don't really need two custom components, since the attributes and behavior are the same. It's just the end markup that is different, thus the two renderers. And it's far easier to switch them - just change a single attribute that identifies the renderer. I can create two custom components and use their own separate renderer as a work around, but it's messy and bloats up app.